ROS carshes with new Ployscope 5.15 (Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver)
I Upgraded my UR5e polyscope to new version 5.15, and running my code using latest Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver 2.
I’m using ROS1 Noetic version
When dashboard’s "speed_scaling_factor" value >= 50% the ROS UR initialize crashed and I got the following message in the dashboard
Wrist 2A: C306A3: Joint: Acceleration failed to pass sanity check

When dashboard’s "speed_scaling_factor" value < 50% - my Application is working fine
Old polyscope version - my Application working fine

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Thanks for your feedback. I found a way to reproduce the problem:
I downloaded the latest Universal_RobotsROS_Driver and the robot crushed when i run the following command:
'roslaunch ur_robot_driver <robot_type>_bringup.launch robot_ip:=192.168.56.101'
Error msg: "Wrist 2A: C306A3: Joint: Acceleration failed to pass sanity check"
its never happen with previous Polyscope versions
